# Receiving SMS issue with SIM900 on arduino

Tags: arduino, sms, sim900

We're having an issue about receiving an SMS with SIM900. According to our program, SMS that we sent is must be in a certain format to be accepted. For example sending `#m1` to Arduino must switch a green LED on and any other texts must be ignored by the program. But now our program accepting all the texts regardless of what is the content of the text and switches on or off the red LED which one is irrelevant.

Can you guys have a look at the codes and find out where is the problem.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(2, 3);

char inchar;
int motor = 4;
int heater = 12;
int sensor = 11;
int counter1;
int heat_degreePin = A0;
int counter;
int buttonState = 0;
String message = "";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(19200);
    pinMode(motor, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
    pinMode(heater, OUTPUT);
    analogReference(INTERNAL);
    digitalWrite(heater, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    SIM900power();
    SIM900.begin(19200);
    delay(20000);
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
    delay(100);
    SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
    delay(100);
}

void loop()
{
    int voltage_value = analogRead(heat_degreePin);
    float heat_degree = heat_degree = voltage_value / 9.31;
    voltage_value = analogRead(heat_degreePin);
    heat_degree = voltage_value / 9.31;
    buttonState = digitalRead(sensor);

    if (heat_degree < 36 && buttonState == LOW && counter != 1) {
        digitalWrite(heater, HIGH);
        delay(50);
        digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
        delay(50);
        message = "D1: heat low: heater on ,moist ok: motor off";
        delay(50);
        SendTextMessage();
        counter = 1;
    }

    else if (heat_degree >= 36 && buttonState == LOW && counter != 2) {
        digitalWrite(heater, LOW);
        delay(50);
        digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
        delay(50);
        message = "D2: heat ok: heater off, moist ok: motor off";
        delay(50);
        SendTextMessage();
        counter = 2;
    }

    else if (heat_degree < 36 && buttonState == HIGH && counter != 3) {
        digitalWrite(heater, HIGH);
        delay(50);
        digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
        delay(50);
        message = "D3: heat low: heater on, moist low: motor on";
        delay(50);
        SendTextMessage();
        counter = 3;
    }

    else if (heat_degree >= 36 && buttonState == HIGH && counter != 4) {
        digitalWrite(heater, LOW);
        delay(50);
        digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
        delay(50);
        message = "D4: heat ok: heater off, moist low: motor on";
        delay(50);
        SendTextMessage();
        counter = 4;
    }

    else {
    }

    if (SIM900.available() > 0) {
        inchar = SIM900.read();

        if (inchar == '#') {
            delay(10);
            inchar = SIM900.read();

            if (inchar == 'm') {
                delay(10);
                inchar = SIM900.read();

                if (inchar == '0') {
                    digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
                    delay(10);
                    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+90505xxxxxxx\"\r");
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println("motor off");
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println((char)26);
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println();
                    delay(5000);
                    SIM900power();
                }
                else if (inchar == '1') {
                    digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
                    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+90505xxxxxxx\"\r");
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println("motor on");
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println((char)26);
                    delay(100);
                    SIM900.println();
                    delay(5000);
                    SIM900power();
                }

                SIM900.println("AT+CMGD=1,4");
            }
        }
    }
}

void SIM900power()
{
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}

void SendTextMessage()
{
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
    delay(500);
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGS=\"+90505xxxxxxx\"\r");
    delay(500);
    SIM900.println(message);
    SIM900.print("\r");
    delay(500);
    SIM900.println((char)26);
    delay(100);
    SIM900.println();
    delay(5000);
    SIM900power();
    delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: What pin are the green and red LED's attached to?